# Declaration error: undeclared identifier error in remix while using exiting Owner contract's function getOwner. Kindly help in solving

Tags: solidity, remix, function

```
function withdraw() external isOwner() {
    address payable owner = address(uint160(getOwner()));//**this is the line I get err
    owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

owner contract:

```
function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
    return owner;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `getOwner()` is marked `external`, and you're calling it internally. If you instead mark `getOwner()` as `public`, it will both be callable from outside *and* inside your contract.